# ExtJS: How to make grid row height grow to fit a block of text?

Tags: extjs, extjs5, sencha-architect

I have a gridpanel that looks like this:

[image]

Defined by:

```
{
    xtype: 'gridpanel',
    title: 'Disclaimer questions',
    bind: {
        store: '{QuestionStore}'
    },
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'labelText',
        text: 'Question text',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'answerings',
        text: 'Answerings',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'answerText',
        text: 'Answer text',
        flex: 1
    }]
}
```

How do you make the rows' heights grow to the size of the text rather than have it cut off with "..."?

Answer (score 3):

As of ExtJS 5, on the column definition, include "cellWrap: true".

```
columns: [{
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    cellWrap: true,   // <---------------------------------------
    dataIndex: 'labelText',
    text: 'Question text',
    flex: 1
}, {
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    dataIndex: 'answerings',
    text: 'Answerings',
    flex: 1
}, {
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    dataIndex: 'answerText',
    text: 'Answer text',
    flex: 1
}]
```

Comment: What about ExtJS4?